# i got this error while trying to run my program after i connected to firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:

Build file 'E:\final_project\android\app\build.gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

\> Could not find method apply() for arguments [[org.gradle.api.plugins.HelpTasksPlugin@3634a04d, org.gradle.buildinit.plugins.BuildInitPlugin@365115ef, org.gradle.buildinit.plugins.WrapperPlugin@37fa35a5, com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.VersionCheckPlugin@77c72672, org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LifecycleBasePlugin@208506c7, org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePlugin@62e96406, org.gradle.api.plugins.JvmEcosystemPlugin@7399fcea, org.gradle.api.plugins.ReportingBasePlugin@18d057c0, org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaBasePlugin$Inject@5c73563, com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin@53ce622a, com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.AppPlugin@1fef87c2, com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin@15377a5c, org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinAndroidPluginWrapper@109168a8, org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.plugins.KotlinScriptBasePlugin@5edbcf9b, Flutter_gradle$FlutterPluginKts@138df070, FlutterPlugin@111a02de]] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:

\> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

\> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

\> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}
apply plugins "com.google.gms.google-services"

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.final_project"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.final_project"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
dependencies {
    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.4.0"))


    // TODO: Add the dependencies for Firebase products you want to use
    // When using the BoM, don't specify versions in Firebase dependencies
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'



    // Add the dependencies for any other desired Firebase products
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the content of `build.gradle` then delete the `build.gradle`

create a new `build.gradle` and paste the previous content to this `build.gradle`

Maybe this will fix your issue.